Blob storage .NET SDK - Paginate AND System.Linq.Async (filters)
I'm having trouble with this documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/pagination#use-systemlinqasync-with-asyncpageable
I want to use System.Linq.Async AND paginate
   AsyncPageable<BlobItem> resultSegment = blobContainerClient.GetBlobsAsync(prefix: prefix);

AsyncPageable implements IAsyncEnumerable
All good and fun, so you can do
    var dateTimeCreatedAgo = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-15);

    AsyncPageable<BlobItem> resultSegment = blobContainerClient.GetBlobsAsync(prefix: prefix)
         .Where(bi => bi.Properties.CreatedOn < dateTimeCreatedAgo)
         .OrderBy(bi => bi.Properties.CreatedOn)
         .Take(takeSize);

This works fine. But here's the probem, i want to have paginated results. With System.Linq.Async it loses the base class of AsyncPageable<BlobItem> which means you can't call AsPages anymore;
    var dateTimeCreatedAgo = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-15);

    AsyncPageable<BlobItem> resultSegment = blobContainerClient.GetBlobsAsync(prefix: prefix)
         .Where(bi => bi.Properties.CreatedOn < dateTimeCreatedAgo)
         .OrderBy(bi => bi.Properties.CreatedOn)
         .Take(takeSize)
     .AsPages(default, segmentSize: 50); // <--- Doesn't work

    AsyncPageable<BlobItem> resultSegment2 = blobContainerClient.GetBlobsAsync(prefix: prefix)
          .AsPages(default, segmentSize: 50); // <-- Works without System.LinqAsync

How can i make this work? Can you have the goods of both worlds?

I think this is happening because you are using Where and OrderBy which gets executed on the client-side and not on the server-side.

So it's not even possible? Even Take(...) works after the .AsPages(..) which limits the total pages. But it doesn't work before .AsPages(...)

There’re very limited server-side options available. I think Take and StartsWith are the two options that you can use.


Blob storage .NET SDK - Paginate AND System.Linq.Async (filters)

I agree with Gaurav Mantri's comment there are very limited server-side options available in the Azure Blob Storage .NET SDK.
You can use the below code with combination of server-side pagination and client-side processing with limited server-side filtering.
Code:
        string connectionString = "connection String";
        string containerName = "test";
        string prefix = "sample";
        int pageSize = 10;
        int pageNumber = 1;
        DateTime dateTimeCreatedAgo = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-3);

        BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString, containerName);

        var paginatedBlobs = await GetPaginatedAndFilteredBlobs(blobContainerClient, prefix, pageSize, dateTimeCreatedAgo, pageNumber);

        foreach (var blob in paginatedBlobs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{blob.Name} - Created On: {blob.Properties.CreatedOn}");
        }
    
    public static async Task<IEnumerable<BlobItem>> GetPaginatedAndFilteredBlobs(
        BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient,
        string prefix,
        int pageSize,
        DateTime dateTimeCreatedAgo,
        int pageNumber)
    {
        var allResults = new List<BlobItem>();
        int skipItems = (pageNumber - 1) * pageSize;

        await foreach (var page in blobContainerClient.GetBlobsAsync(prefix: prefix).AsPages(default, pageSize))
        {
            allResults.AddRange(page.Values);

            if (allResults.Count >= (pageNumber * pageSize))
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        var filteredAndSortedResults = allResults
            .Where(bi => bi.Properties.CreatedOn < dateTimeCreatedAgo)
            .OrderBy(bi => bi.Properties.CreatedOn)
            .Skip(skipItems)
            .Take(pageSize);

        return filteredAndSortedResults;

Here, I checked with 3 days of blob data with filter.
Output:
sample - Created On: 26-06-2024 04:01:55 +00:00
sample/gnupg-2.4.5.tar.bz2.sig - Created On: 26-06-2024 04:02:15 +00:00
sample/industry.csv - Created On: 26-06-2024 04:02:15 +00:00
sample/industry.csv.gpg - Created On: 26-06-2024 04:02:15 +00:00
sample/sample2.ps1 - Created On: 26-06-2024 04:02:15 +00:00

Reference:
Pagination with the Azure SDK for .NET - .NET | Microsoft Learn
